# Run Laravel on existing Apache server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ubuntu-14.04

I have a DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using this as a host for my web-development projects.
Now I want to start using Laravel for a project of mine, but I have a question about this.

In the /var/www/html folder of Ubuntu I created a folder, let's say, "project". In this folder I installed Laravel using [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation) tutorial. Now everything is setup I want to run Laravel so I can test it and start developing on it.
When I run the command `php artisan serve` from within the "project"-folder it says "running on http://localhost:8000". So it's working.
But how do I access it? When I go to http://example.com/project it just shows me the files in that folder.

So it's running on the localhost on my server. Does that mean that it is external-accesible (the url above) or how does this work? (I guess the port is also different, 8000 instead of the default 80 for Apache)

I hope the question is clear and someone can help me out.

Comment: Normally it's only for use on a local server. You should install PHP on your local machine then run `php artisan serve` on your computer until you're ready to publish it on a live website.

Comment: I have php installed. Can I install it in a sub folder of the localhost root?

Comment: Probably this question should be on SuperUser

Comment: Actually I thought about that. Is it possible to move the question or should a mod do that?

Comment: @JeroenJK When using `artisan` you can place you folder wherever you like. All you do is browse to the folder in a command window and type `php artisan serve`, then open your browser and type in `http://localhost:8000` (change the port if you're not using the default artisan port).

Comment: Yeah it's working now. Looks very cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Laravel project up and running on Digital Ocean with the Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic (1221) kernal.

I don't think you should be using `php artisan serve` for this purpose, as that is more for your local computer if you would like to preview your webpage if you don't want to use Apache.

To get set up, I used the excellent below instructions that were incredibly helpful.  As you can see, there are many steps that you should carefully follow to get things up and running.

[https://github.com/susanBuck/dwa15-fall2016-notes/blob/master/01_Servers_and_Git/07_Deploy_to_Digital_Ocean.md](https://github.com/susanBuck/dwa15-fall2015-notes/blob/master/01_Servers_and_Git/10_Deploy_to_Digital_Ocean.md)

Let me know if that helps you, and feel free to follow up with more questions if you get stuck on a step.

Comment: Well, it seems like a lot of work for what I want to achieve now (just test Laravel and see what's possible) so I won't do that now. When I finished a project I need to run publicly I will look into it! Thank you!

Comment: This link is no longer available? Does anyone have a copy of it? or a link to an updated version?

Comment: @guyver4mk Here you go:  https://github.com/susanBuck/dwa15-fall2015-notes/blob/master/01_Servers_and_Git/10_Deploy_to_Digital_Ocean.md

Comment: The link looks like it's shifted to this https://github.com/susanBuck/dwa15-fall2016-notes/blob/master/01_Servers_and_Git/07_Deploy_to_Digital_Ocean.md ... I've commented that part out, Once you check it, Please edit it back in